# How to get top 1 record of each group based on where clause using group by column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want the top 1 record of each group, group column is `imei`. If user has multiple devices, it should show the latest record of all devices.

SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    p.imei, DEVICEID, timestatmp, ph, do, temp 
FROM 
    dbo.pond AS p
INNER JOIN 
    customerdevices AS cd ON p.imei = cd.imei  
INNER JOIN
    users AS u ON cd.CustomerId = u.CustomerId 
WHERE
    u.username = 'bob'  
ORDER BY
   timestatmp DESC
```

Sample data

```
imei            DEVICEID    timestatmp            ph     do     temp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
869668021752476 1027    2020-03-16 04:33:00.617 7.86    5.04    22.52
869668021752476 1027    2020-03-16 04:03:00.957 7.88    4.99    22.59
869668021732924 1025    2020-03-16 03:57:01.130 7.39    5.40    21.85
```

Expected output:

```
imei            DEVICEID    timestatmp            ph     do     temp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
869668021752476 1027    2020-03-16 04:33:00.617 7.86    5.04    22.52
869668021732924 1025    2020-03-16 03:57:01.130 7.39    5.40    21.85
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```
SELECT 
imei,
DEVICEID,
timestatmp,
ph,
do,
temp FROM
(
SELECT 
p.imei,
DEVICEID,
timestatmp,
ph,
do,
temp,
RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.imei ORDER BY timestatmp DESC) 
FROM dbo.pond as p
inner JOIN customerdevices as cd ON p.imei = cd.imei  inner Join users
as u on cd.CustomerId = u.CustomerId where u.username='bob' )
T
Where T.RN=1 order by timestatmp desc
```

Comment: getting error - The multi-part identifier "p.imei" could not be bound.

Comment: @getting correct output , but is the code is good, its looking too lengthy and complicated.

Comment: @krishnamohan Picking up a `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery is the most standard way of solving this problem. It's not "too lengthy and complicated". It's standard and rote. Learn about window functions because they are a very valuable tool.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in conjunction with `ROW_NUMBER`, to stick with your current approach:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES p.imei, DEVICEID, timestatmp, ph, do, temp
FROM dbo.pond AS p
INNER JOIN customerdevices AS cd
    ON p.imei = cd.imei
INNER JOIN users AS u
    ON cd.CustomerId = u.CustomerId
WHERE u.username = 'bob'
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.imei, DEVICEID ORDER BY timestatmp DESC);
```

This trick works because all records retained would have a row number of value of 1, which would only occur for the latest record, for each `imei` and `DEVICEID` group.

Comment: this is not working , can u check once, still getting multiple records of the same imei.

Comment: Do those mutiple records also happen to have the same timestamp?  If so, what would be the logic for breaking a tie and choosing just one of those records?